# Disable gnome-screenshot's 'camera flash' animation

Tags: gnome, screenshot, dconf, gnome-screenshot

How can I disable the gnome-screenshot 'camera flash' animation (fade from black)?   I've already disabled the camera shutter sound with `sudo mv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/camera-shutter.oga /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/camera-shutter-disabled.oga`.  There doesn't seem to be a setting for this in the Dconf editor (under `/org/gnome/gnome-screenshot`).

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately there is no option to disable this... I was looking for working tool to grab screen for Ubuntu Focal (previously I've used `scrot` but it stopped to work, right now only `gnome-screenshot` is still dumping screen content to file but with annoying flash). So I've recompiled sources from https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-screenshot

1. `git clone https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-screenshot.git && cd gnome-screenshot`
2. In file `src/screenshot-backend-shell.c` replace all occurrences of `TRUE, /* flash */` with `FALSE, /* flash */`  (you can do that with sed command: `sed -i 's#TRUE, /\* flash \*/#FALSE, /\* flash \*/#' src/screenshot-backend-shell.c`)
3. Install dependencies (in my case it was `meson`, `ninja-build`, `libgtk-3-dev` and `libhandy-1-dev`)
4. Compile project:

   - `meson setup build`
   - `meson test -C build`
5. Enjoy your new `gnome-screenshot` tool without flash: `./build/src/gnome-screenshot --file out.jpg`

Comment: In my case I also had to install `gettext`

Answer (score 0):

Disable Wayland

```
nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Add an entry

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

save

```
service gdm3 restart
```